# How to use krpano tools to generate tiles for marzipano viewer

Tags: panoramas, 360-degrees, 360-panorama, 360-panorama-viewer, krpano

I have a spherical source photos which I would like to display in marzipano viewer. Displaying it directly with `Marzipano.EquirectGeometry` works well but user has to wait until the whole image is loaded (few megas) so we'll have to switch to tiles for better experience.

So I used krpano tools to generate tiles from sphere (I'll use it on server, so marzipano tool is not an option). 
Tried with `maketiles`, `sphere2cube` and with `MAKE PANO (MULTIRES) droplet.bat` but just can't figure out what I am really doing.

For example, marzipano viewer uses `/{z}/{f}/{y}/{x}.jpg` formula for getting tiles, while `maketiles` uses `tiles_%v_%h.jpg` (just 2 values?) for generating them.

`MAKE PANO (MULTIRES) droplet.bat` generates something else. The formula is `tiles/[mres_c/]l%Al/%Av/l%Al[_c]_%Av_%Ah.jpg` and result looks like:

- C:\krpano\IMG.tiles\mres_b\l1\1\l1_b_1_1.jpg
- C:\krpano\IMG.tiles\mres_b\l1\1\l1_b_1_2.jpg
- C:\krpano\IMG.tiles\mres_b\l1\2\l1_b_2_1.jpg
- .....
- C:\krpano\IMG.tiles\mres_b\l2\2\l2_b_2_3.jpg

What exactly do I have to do with krpano tools to get `/{z}/{f}/{y}/{x}.jpg` type tiles from spherical 360 image?

Comment: We moved to krpano viewer which also looks great and works out of the box with krpano.

Answer (score -4):

I'm trying the same, time ago I did with Pannellum https://pannellum.org/

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because while it might be a valid solution, it does not address the fundamental question posed.